# Shell32 reference error with older .Shell32.dll version?

Tags: c#

I inherited a project built on a Windows 2008 R2 box, and it makes reference to the Shell32.dll.

I need this project to work on a Windows 2003 box, and it seems the Shell32.dll doesnt contain a "Target" method on the W2003 box.

Is there an equivalent method or way of doing this?

Here is code:

```
serverlink = (ShellLinkObject)serverlinkfile.GetLink;
string spath = serverlink.Target.Path;
```

This is the error VS2010 is giving me:

> 'Shell32.ShellLinkObject' does not contain a definition for 'Target' and no extension method 'Target' accepting a first arguement of type 'Shell32.ShellLinkObject' could be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )

UPDATED - NEW ERROR:

> Object reference not set to instance of an object

OFFENDING CODE ( Shell32.FolderItems items = sourceFolder.Items(); )

```
FileSystemObject fso = new FileSystemObject();
if (!fso.FolderExists(destPath))
{
fso.CreateFolder(destPath);
}
ShellClass sc = new ShellClass();
Shell32.Folder sourceFolder = sc.NameSpace(sourcePath);
Shell32.Folder destFolder = sc.NameSpace(destPath);
Shell32.FolderItems items = sourceFolder.Items();
```

Comment: Shell32 is not a managed DLL, how are you referencing the Shell32 dll? Are you using a wrapper library, COM interop, or something else entirely?

Comment: It is added as a reference to the project and I am just using the "using Shell32;"

Comment: Yes, and the .NET framework does not come with a  `Shell32` namespace. My question is what did you do to get Shell32 included in to your project? Did you add a refrence to the `Microsoft Shell Cotnrolls and Automation` com object, [a external library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), or something else.

Comment: The project came with two dlls, Interop.Shell32.dll and Interop.Scripting.dll, which are added as references to the project as "Shell32" and "Scripting"... When I get rid of the offending method "Target" and just use string spath = serverlink.Path; It then complains about the two Interop DLLs targetting a different processor than the application. The project build settings are set to target "Any CPU".

Comment: The Interop.*.dll format tells us you are using a COM object. If you remove it from the project and [re-add the COM refrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) it does it work then?

Comment: Removing and adding from the COM removed the compile errors and warnings, but now I get a new object reference null error on the code I added in the updated post above. Progress!

Comment: I think I know why it is erroring out here. Couple more tests and I think I may have it working.. Ill keep you posted, thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: Removing the references and re-adding them through COM worked, and also removing the Target and using Path worked. Can I add to your reputation based on the comments you left, or can I only upvote the partial answer below? Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer, feel free to upvote me but Hans really deserves being marked as the correct answer as I think the `Target` issue is the bigger issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target is not [a documented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for ShellLinkObject.  Otherwise the hazard of trying to run code on a 10 year old operating system.

Use the [Path property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  Afaik it must be a physical path, not a virtual shell folder.

Answer (score 0):

Often when working with COM and changing build platforms if the environment was not set up correctly you can get the errors like you are getting.

By removing the COM reference and re-adding it that will sometimes fix the issue.